# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "٠"

Tags: java, android, localization, number-formatting

So I'm getting a crash `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "٠"` because for some reason on Egyptian devices the decimal delimiter is ٠ instead of .
How do I solve this? It can handle users who have , (comma) as the decimal symbol, but this weird dot causes a crash. Here's the code that's the problem:

```
DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
oneDigit.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
sevenDaysAverage = Float.valueOf(oneDigit.format(sevenDaysAverage));  // exception here
```

My goal is to have a number formatted with a single decimal delimited by a dot, because the app is in English and that's how the number should be displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the decimal separator. When I Google it I see that it is the [Arabic numeral zero](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%A0).

Answer (score 4):

```
String f = "20.0"; // suppose . is weird symbol  
String f1 = f.replace(".","."); // replace weird dot with decimal point
```

Then convert `f1` to `String`.

```
sevenDaysAverage = Float.valueOf(f1);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an Arabic Zero not a decimal point,

Answer (score 0):

You ought to use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class.It allows you to parse Strings into a locale aware number. This would prevent you from facing situations where the decimal separator character is `,` For example in case of *German*, it would be:

```java
NumberFormat nf_ge = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);

String number_ge = nf_ge.format(1000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the grouping separator to be a point, you can use an european locale:

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
```

Alternatively you can use the `DecimalFormatSymbols` class to change the symbols that appear in the formatted numbers produced by the format method. These symbols include the decimal separator, the grouping separator, the minus sign, and the percent sign, among others:

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
    otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.'); 
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(formatString, otherSymbols);
```